# Troubleshooting a Watermark Issue - Need Guidance

Tags: image, upgrade, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm a Magento newbie. Just upgraded a site from 1.6.2 to 1.8.1, and now watermarks which were working in 1.6.2 are not appearing correctly on product images. (Should be in the lower right corner, and they are there, but the entire watermark is not being displayed - just the upper half of the watermark. However the entire product image is being displayed, so the issue is definitely with the watermark and not a cropping problem with the product image.) The product images are either .jpg or .png, and the watermark is a transparent .png. Where would you suggest I start to troubleshoot a problem like this? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you checked if the sizes in System->Configuration->Design -- Product Image Watermark . agree with the sizes of your watermarks?

Comment: Yiorgos, I did not think of checking that because I assumed they were matched up in the previous version and that would not have changed with the 1.8.1 upgrade! Thank you for the idea. I'll check it out.

Comment: @JRDixey did you ever fix this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same problem but with one difference. It has just happened with a bunch of images related to USBs. It's nonsense because they are also .jpg.
Tried to clear images chache with no success... I'm in 1.8.1 as well but it's not an upgrade problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the images cache in

```
System -> Cache Management -> Clear Images Cache
```